# Stop automatic reinstall of drivers in drivercache

Tags: windows, installation, drivers

So, you've got a driver that's giving you problems and you uninstall the driver or device and it automatically gets reinstalled.

- Is there a way to stop windows from keeping a driver in the driver cache?
- Is there an easy way to remove them?

I can find out which files are used, search and remove them manually, but it's a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boot in diagnostic mode (F5 at boot), and if you remove the device now, the drivers will go too